# Are there any good ways to plot (or illustrate) how one dependent variable is affected by another 4 independent variables at the same time?

Tags: graphing-functions, data-analysis

There are four independent variables (i.e., a,b,c,d) that affect the dependent variable (s) at the same time. 
Can we use only one figure to show their relationship? For example, in 2D, we can plot the relationship of two variables in one figure with Cartesian coordinate system. In 3d, we can plot the relationship of three variables in space coordinate system. Can we show the relationship of 5 variables in one figure？
If not, are there any good ways to illustrate how one dependent variable is affected by another 4 independent variables?